# Tic Tac Toe game over Bluetooth android, playing turn by turn?

Tags: android, bluetooth, tic-tac-toe, android-bluetooth

I might not be able to express exactly what problem I am having, but I can try.
I am working on a Bluetooth Tic Tac Toe Game over android OS. I have developed it.
But now I have a problem, I am able to play it over bluetooth, transfer the code, set the desired "X" or "O", but when I transfer the info to be set, I expect other player to wait. Is there any mechanism that can enable me to stop my "board" if my turn is over. And Just when Other user over bluetooth connection transfer she should have her board disabled or on hold and my board should be enabled. 
currently, both boards are open for random connection, anyone after connecting, can transfer asynchronously. 
Any expert help would be appreciated.

(I have used treads for transfer, connect, and server actions)

Comment: I didn't fully understand the question. do u want to disable the board whenever its the other players turn?

Comment: @Tom thanks for the reply.
I wanna disable the 9 imagebuttons which I have used for the tiatactoe board. I know I can disable them by using `ibutton.setClickable(false);` but problem then arises is that I have used this method already while each imagebutton(from 9 boardbuttons) is clicked. This is to prevent another multiple click on the same previously clicked button. so, If I try doing `setClickable(false)` on whole board(9 image buttons), I end up disabling them, but when I need to re-enable them, I should be able to re-enable only those buttons which are yet to be clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should "remember" which buttons were are unclicked before you disable the whole board and then re-enable them when its this players turn..
it really depends on your implementation.. if u decide to extend button then add a boolean field "clicked" and then iterate over the 9 buttons and enable only the ones with clicked=false.
another option is just save the button numbers which have been clicked if you are using a grid or some kind of collection to store them.

again, im not sure what u did because u didnt post any code but i advise u to think it over and decide how do u represent a tic-tac-toe button in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Tom.
I had to reshuffle quite a lot of code.
What I have done is "remembered" which imagebuttons were pressed and which were not, and then at the time of disabling the buttons (when it was other users turn), I disabled imagebuttons which were yet to be clicked. A simple flag mechanism was what I applied. Sometimes, a common way of solving things is quite uncommon.
Thanks for helping